# pl/sql quotes exception

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

How to resolve exceptions when I'm passing '+' to second parameter ? I was trying `Value_error` `invalid_number` but it is not working.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE z33(number1 number,number2 number,character     varchar2)
 IS
sum number(3);

BEGIN

IF ( character= '+' ) THEN
   sum := number1 + number2;
 ELSIF ( character= '-' ) THEN
   sum := number1 - number2;
 ELSIF ( character= '*' ) THEN
   sum := number1 * number2;
ELSIF ( character= '/' ) THEN
   sum := number1 / number2;
ELSE
   dbms_output.put_line('bad character');
END IF;
dbms_output.put_line('sum ' || sum) ;
EXCEPTION
WHEN ZERO_DIVIDE THEN  
  dbms_output.put_line('dont do that!!');
WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN 
  dbms_output.put_line('error in input');
WHEN OTHERS THEN 
  dbms_output.put_line('other error');
END;


Begin

z33(1,'+','+');

end;
```

.......

Comment: it's impossibile to pass '+' as second parameter (and have no sense). You can try z33(1, 2, '+')

Comment: You could define the `number1` and `number2` parameters as `VARCHAR2` and then convert them in the body of the procedure with `TO_NUMBER()`. Or you could overload the procedure.

Answer (score 2):

It's that you're never even getting into your procedure. If you want to catch that error, it's from the call itself that you have catch the exception, for example:

```
begin
  z33(1,'+','+');
exception
  when value_error then
    dbms_output.put_line('Invalid parameter in call');
end;
/
```

Result in Dbms Output:

```
Invalid parameter in call
```

Answer (score 0):

In the above case, the exception is raised while passing parameters to the procedure z33. Procedure can only handle the exceptions that are raised in execution block. In this case, the exception will propogate to the outer environment (i.e your calling env). Use exception in the calling block, you can catch it....